# Applications relying on multiplication of large matrices

Tags: matrices, reference-request, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am currently working on a parallel implementation of dense matrix-matrix multiplication. For motivation, I am looking for real-world examples that rely on multiplying large matrices (as possible for matrices of size $>2^{30}\times2^{30})$. Can someone please help me to find references to such applications? I heard that in weather prediction large matrices have to multiplied but I was not able to find according references.

Comment: I am not an expert on that subject. If you use the boundary element method, e.g. on applications such as electromagnetism or acoustics, you will get dense matrices. Maybe you will find something about matrix-matrix multiplication in that area. (Ususally one avoids any kind of matrix-matrix multiplication, though.)

Comment: You can use Spark or Pyspark in Python and also a single machine proposal http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dongz/15-740/\